# Как работает округление в R с точностью до знака

Tags: r

`Browse[2]> print(round(0.199999999999, 1), digits=20)
[1] 0.20000000000000001`

Что происходит? Я ожидал увидеть точное 0.2. Зачем нужна функция округления если ее результат снова нужно округлять?

При этом:

`Browse[2]> round(0.199999999999, 1)==0.2
[1] TRUE`

Т.е. окргуляет правильно, но print( ,digits=20) неправильно печатает?

Answer (score 1):

Просто "точные" числа в 10-ричной системе могут оказаться иррациональными в 2-чной. Подробнее см. https://habrahabr.ru/post/337260/